# Why would spawning a process make computation run twice as fast?

Tags: multithreading, performance, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

The following computation takes about 10.4 seconds on my Precision 5520:

```py
import time
before = time.time()
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 100000000):
    sum += i
print(time.time() - before, sum)
```

On the same laptop, the following takes only 5.2 seconds:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def foo():
    before = time.time()
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, 100000000):
        sum += i
    print(time.time() - before, sum)

mp.Process(target=foo).start()
```

This result is consistent. In fact, it holds (with a slightly smaller speed-up factor) even if I run `cpu_count` processes simultaneously.

So, why would spawning a process make computation run twice as fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the process that make the computation fast, it is running the computation in a function. This is because **global variable accesses are slower than local variable accesses using the CPython interpreter**. If you simply run `foo()` in the same process, then the computation time is also twice lower. Here is an example:

```py
import time

def foo():
    before = time.time()
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, 100000000):
        sum += i
    print(time.time() - before, sum)

# Slow (8.806 seconds)
before = time.time()
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 100000000):
    sum += i
print(time.time() - before, sum)

# Fast (4.362 seconds)
foo()
```

Note overwriting the built-in function `sum` is a bit dangerous as it may break codes using it and cause weird errors.

Comment: Is this an artifact of CPython or something more general?

Comment: This impact the *CPython bytecode* which is generally used by other implementations. The function case do a [`LOAD_FAST`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8122e8d5017be9f0683a49bc20d3c82e8b5398d6/Python/ceval.c#L1864) instruction while the global case does a [`LOAD_NAME`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8122e8d5017be9f0683a49bc20d3c82e8b5398d6/Python/ceval.c#L2990). As you may see there is much more work to be done for `LOAD_NAME`. Other implementation can use this bytecode. They may optimize that better but `LOAD_NAME` should be generally a bit more expensive.

Comment: Such behaviour might be shared by some other interpreted languages. This should not be the case for compiled languages like C and C++ as long as the variable is `static` (though it is dependent of the platform and mainly the compiler). It is hard to generalize the rule but I expect local variables to be better optimized than global because compiler/runtimes can make stronger assumptions on local variables, so they can apply more advanced optimizations.